# Differences between jsf with and without jboss

Tags: java, jsf, jboss

It has been almost a month since i started working with jsf and jboss. I've worked with jsf before. But i didn't use jboss, just apache with it.

I've done a bit of search and i found that JBOSS is:

```
WildFly, formerly known as JavaBeans Open Source Software Application Server is an application server that implements the Java Platform, Enterprise Edition. JBoss is written in Java and as such is cross-platform: usable on any operating system that supports Java.
```

And instead of managed beans, there are Action classes. As far as i know, the concept is the same, but some annotations are different.

Are these the only differences between jsf with and without jboss? What good does it do in a jsf application? Is jboss really required?

Comment: What do you mean by Action classes?I've never heard of them in context of JSF

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need specifically JBoss AS (now Wildfly, the name has been recently changed) but you obviously need some web container (de facto web server) which run JSF applications (for instance Tomcat, Jetty, Resin or Wildfly).

Difference between plain web container (Tomcat, Jetty) and application server (Wildfly, Glassfish) is that in AS you can use Java EE technologies like EJB or JMS. For JSF the difference is that JSF libraries are usually bundled with application server so you don't have to put them into your WAR file (or have scope `provided` in Maven).

Comment: Hmm..i see. In fact, my friend here told me that there are some parts in the project with hibernate. Oh yeah...what what is this "Seam" thing?

Comment: Seam was a framework created to ease using of Java EE technologies (like JSF) - nowadays is mostly replaced by Apache Delta Spike so it's not under active development anymore.